# Number of times one string occurs within another in C

Tags: c, string

I have written a function that uses the strstr() function to determine if string2 has any matches in string1. This works fine (I also convert both strings to lower case so that I can do a case-insensitive match.). However, strstr() only finds the *first* time the match occurs. Is there a way to use it to find *each* time a match occurs? For example:

```
string1[] = "ABCDEFABC";
string2[] = "ABC";
```

Would return 0 as a match is found in position 0, and 6 as it's found again in position 6?

Here's the original function as written (including call to function in main):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



char *strstrnc(const char *str1, const char *str2);

int main()
{
    char buf1[80],buf2[80];

    printf("Enter the first string to be compared: ");
    gets(buf1);
    printf("Enter the second string to be compared: ");
    gets(buf2);

    strstrnc(buf1,buf2);

    return 0;
}


char *strstrnc(const char *buf1, const char *buf2)
{
    char *p1, *ptr1, *p2, *ptr2, *loc;
    int ctr;

    ptr1 = malloc(80 * sizeof(char));
    ptr2 = malloc(80 * sizeof(char));


    p1 = ptr1;
    p2 = ptr2;



    for (ctr = 0; ctr < strlen(buf1);ctr++)
    {
        *p1++ = tolower(buf1[ctr]);
    }
    *p1 = '\0';

    for (ctr = 0; ctr < strlen(buf2);ctr++)
    {
        *p2++ = tolower(buf2[ctr]);
    }
    *p2 = '\0';

    printf("The new first string is %s.\n", ptr1);
    printf("The new first string is %s.\n", ptr2);

    loc = strstr(ptr1,ptr2);
    if  (loc == NULL)
    {
        printf("No match was found!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s was found at position %ld.\n", ptr2, loc-ptr1);
    }

    return loc;

}
```

Comment: Call `strstr()` in a loop until it returns null, starting one character after where it matched the previous time (at the beginning of the string on the first time, of course).

Comment: (_Maybe you would have heard this_ ) Please don't use `gets` .

Comment: Why did you use `%ld` specifier to print `loc-ptr1` ?

Comment: @ameyCU Right, I see all the compiler warnings for gets ("it's unsafe"). Interestingly, though, the book I'm using uses "gets" all the time.

Comment: Well, you should buy a newer book :). Gets is deprecated

Comment: @Michi Yes, book is a few years old :-).

Comment: `gets()` will write input data in the memory without looking at the size  of the buffer. That means there is a possibility that `gets()` will write pass the end of the array if the input string is too large..

Comment: @ameyCU I understand, wouldn't use it in production code.

Comment: If the input was `ABABA` and you are searching for `ABA`, what is the number of occurrence that you expect..? 1 or 2..?

Comment: @Ramesh-X One. Looking for exact match of entire string.

Comment: Change the value of `offset` to length of searching string in R Sahu's answer.. It will work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    char string1[] = "ABCDABCEFABC";
    char string2[] = "ABC";
    char *s1, *s2, *s3;

    size_t lenstring1 = strlen(string1);
    size_t lenstring2 = strlen(string2);

    if (lenstring2 < 1){
        printf("There is no substring found"); /* or what ever */
        exit(1);
    }

    size_t i=0,j=0;
    int found=0;

    s1 = string1;
    s2 = string2;


    for(i = 0; i < lenstring1; i++){
        if(*s1 == *s2){
              s3 = s1;
              for(j = 0;j < lenstring2;j++){
                if(*s3 == *s2){
                  s3++;s2++;
                }else{
                    break;
                }
              }

              s2 = string2;

              if(j == strlen(string2)){
                 found = 1;
                printf("%s found at index : %zu\n",string2,i+1);
              }
          }
        s1++;
    }

    if(found == 0){
        printf("No match Found");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> ABC found at index : 1
> ABC found at index : 5
> ABC found at index : 10
> ```

If the **string2** is empty you will get:

> There is no substring found

Comment: 1) This code prints nothing when `char string2[] = "";`  OP has not defined what is expected in this corner case.  Printing nothing is reasonable.  2) `printf("\%s...` is a problem as `\%` is unknown escape sequence.

Comment: @chux he did, when he showed he's first string **ABCDEFABC**, about **\** you right :).

Comment: @chux What exactly should print if string2[] = "" ? and by the way, here are a lot of people with only theory's please don't become one of them :).

Comment: "What exactly should print if `string2[] = ""`"  --> These are reasons for returning a match for each postilion in `string1[]`, only 1 at the end of `string1[]` or no match.  This answer did the last. Which is right?, ask OP. I am not trying to comment what is right amongst reasonable alternatives,  just noting this answer did not have bad behavior, like the [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32997838/number-of-times-one-string-occurs-within-another-in-c/32998088#comment53822912_32998088) in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32998088/2410359).

Comment: @chux I hadn't considered a null search string to be honest. The second answer does take care of this potential scenario. Alternatively, I could still use first answer and just not allow a null search string.

Comment: @user3712321 Whatever works for you = its your post.  Checking for edge conditions if too often ignored and leads to hacker exploits.  IMO, wise to not assume input data is friendly.

Answer (score 3):

Given

```
char string1[] = "ABCDEFABC";
char string2[] = "ABC";
```

`strstr(string1, string2)` will return a pointer to the first element of `string1`.

> Would return 0 as a match is found in position 0, and 6 as it's found again in position 6?

In order to check for multiple occurrences of `string2` in `string1`, you'll have to call `strstr` multiple times with an offset from `string1`. E.g.

```
char* found = strstr(string1, string2);
while ( found != NULL )
{
   // Search for string2 after applying an offset.
   int offset = 1;
   found = strstr(found+offset, string2);
}
```

Comment: @user3712321, it's hard telling what could be wrong with out seeing what you tried. That's why we emphasize on posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry, comment got cut off before I could post code. Here it is:

`loc = strstr(ptr1,ptr2);


    while (loc != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s was found at position %ld.\n", ptr2, loc-ptr1);
        int offset = strlen(ptr2);
        loc = strstr(loc + offset, ptr2);
        printf("%s was found at position %ld.\n", ptr2, loc-ptr1);
    }`

Comment: Results of running code:  

Enter the first string to be compared: abcdefabc  
Enter the second string to be compared: abc  
The new first string is abcdefabc.  
The new second string is abc.  
abc was found at position 0.  
abc was found at position 6.  
abc was found at position 6.  
abc was found at position -32374800.

Comment: Remove the second `printf` inside the `while` loop.

Comment: Nice tight solution.  Corner case problem: Should `string2[0] == 0`, code  --> UB as it increments beyond the end of `string1`.

Comment: @user3712321 Ty my Answer too?